# Is it possible to show an element just before entering a long running sync process?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

This is a very simple use case. Show an element (a loader), run some heavy calculations that eat up the thread and hide the loader when done. I am unable to get the loader to actually show up prior to starting the long running process. It ends up showing and hiding after the long running process. Is adding css classes an async process?

See my jsbin here:

http://jsbin.com/voreximapewo/12/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: you can setTimeout on the workload, or affect some dom layout-causing properties (which i can't recall ATM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain what a few others have pointed out: This is due to how the browser queues the things that it needs to do (i.e. run JS, respond to UI events, update/repaint how the page looks etc.). When a JS function runs, it prevents all those other things from happening until the function returns.

Take for example:

```
function work() {

    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
        arr.join(',');
    }

    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = "done";

}

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function() {

    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = "thinking...";
    work();

};
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/7bpzuLmp/)

Clicking the button here will change the `innerHTML` of the div, and then call `work`, which should take a second or two. And although the div's `innerHTML` has changed, the browser doesn't have chance to update how the actual page looks until the event handler has returned, which means waiting for `work` to finish. But by that time, the div's `innerHTML` has changed again, so that when the browser does get chance to repaint the page, it simply displays 'done' without displaying 'thinking...' at all.

We can, however, do this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function() {

    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = "thinking...";
    setTimeout(work, 1);

};
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/7bpzuLmp/1/)

`setTimeout` works by putting a call to a given function at the back of the browser's queue after the given time has elapsed. The fact that it's placed at the back of the queue means that it'll be called after the browser has repainted the page (since the previous HTML changing statement would've queued up a repaint before `setTimeout` added `work` to the queue), and therefore the browser has had chance to display 'thinking...' before starting the time consuming `work`.

So, basically, use `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

let the current frame render and start the process after `setTimeout(1)`.

alternatively you could query a property and force a repaint like this: `element.clientWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

More as a what is possible answer you can make your calculations on a new thread using HTML5 Web Workers
This will not only make your loading icon appear but also keep it loading.

More info about web workers : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/